# IntelliJ can't locate file by it's relative path, only absolute

Tags: file, intellij-idea, filepath

In my project I need to use 3 .wav files which I play. The files are located in the same directory as the class in which I use their paths. The problem is I can hear a sound only when I specify the absolute path to the files. When I use relative paths it's not working. I tried a lot of combinations but none of them works. I need to use relative paths because it's a plugin project. When I inject File reference containing only file's name IntelliJ can see the file, but the reference is only temporary and it obviously doesn't solve my problem. [My directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/est2x.png)
My current paths:

```
private String soundLevel1 = "/de/halirutan/keypromoterx/sound_effects/duck_quack_sound_effect.wav";
```

My File object:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
```

My audio start:

```
AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();
    try (AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)) {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        try (clip) {
            clip.addLineListener(listener);
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
            listener.waitUntilDone();
        }
```

Comment: please add your code for setting relative path

Comment: The screenshot of my current paths is linked in my question. I ntried setting the path many different ways but it's not working.

Comment: That are not a paths, this are file names. Provide the code how you call it?

Comment: I inserted the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

try to read the file with

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(soundLevel1);
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

with `getClass().getResource()` you are reads a file in your project

Comment: It isn't working. Maybe the problem is it is a plugin?

Comment: what error do you receive by execution with relative path? If it works with absolute path, the problem is definitely in your code.

Comment: and make the resources in your `src/de/halirutan/keypromoterx` folder. Outside of project it would of cource not work

Comment: There's only problem with the sound, icons are stored in the same directory as my .wav files and they are being displayed without any problem

Comment: Quesiton title **IntelliJ can't locate file by it's relative path, only absolute**. you say **There's only problem with the sound**. i am speechless

Comment: So I guess you're not going to help me?

Comment: i will, but i dont know how, if you have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

wav with **absolute** path is played, with **relative** not.

The **problem** is with **the sound**, **not** with **reading directory** (that is a question title)

You have **no errors**.

make before `clip.start();` `System.out.println("play");` and look if it is executed